# how to access the constructor of one class from another class in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I’ve two classes namely `adminglobal.as` and `company.as`.

I need to access the constructor present inside `adminglobal.as` from `company.as`. Also when accessing I need to use the variables present inside the constructor from `company.as` too.

Basically what I need is to call the constructor in `adminglobal.as` from company.as and use the variables present inside the constructor in `company.as`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a class `AdminGlobal` in a file named `adminglobal.as` and a class `Company` in a file `company.as`. To access the constructor of one class inside the other, you only have to make that class **public** and then import that class, if they are placed in different packages. If they are in the same package then you don't need to implicitly import the class.

In order to use the variables and methods from one class in another you only need to make sure that those variables and methods are marked as **public** as well. I suggest you take a look at [this tutorial from Kirupa about Classes in ActionScript3](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/classes_as3_pg1.htm).

For example, if you have `adminglobal.as` inside a folder named `admins`, the route would be: `your_project_folder/src/admins/adminglobal.as`

And example contents of class `AdminGlobal`:

```
package admins
{
  public class AdminGlobal
  {
    //accesible variable
    public var name:String;

    //constructor
    public function AdminGlobal()
    {
      //do init stuff here
      name= "anon";
    }

  }

}
```

And if you have your class Company in the file company.as in the src folder of your project (default package), the route would be: `your_project_folder/src/company.as`

And example contents of class `Company`, accessing class `AdminGlobal`:

```
package
{
  //import public class from another package
  import admins.AdminGlobal;

  public class Company
  {

    //constructor
    public function Company()
    {
      //call constructor of public class
      var ag:AdminGlobal = new AdminGlobal();

      //access public variables
      trace(ag.name);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "public static var" to reach a variable from other classes.

For Example;

```
package com
{
    public class DataVO
    {
        public static var version:String = "1";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just thinking through this the wrong way, you can have arguments/parameters for your constructor, so AdminGlobal could be declared like

```
public AdminGlobal(companyId:Number,companyName:String);
```

then in Company you could call

```
new AdminGlobal(this.companyId,this.companyName);
```

and do whatever you need to do with those variables in the constructor of AdminGlobal

Or even

```
AdminGlobal(company:Company);
```

then in Company do

```
new AdminGlobal(this);
```

and you have a handle on any public members of Company from AdminGlobal;